# Pandas data cleansing to assign records below a row are assigned a particular value

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

In the below code, I'm using simple data manipulation to split the columns and remove unnecessary characters.

```
input_uni_towns = pd.read_fwf("university_towns.txt", sep = " ", header = None)
uni_towns = input_uni_towns.rename(columns={0: "Raw_data"})
uni_towns['Cleaned'] = uni_towns["Raw_data"].replace(regex=True,to_replace=[r'\[[^()]*\]'],value=r'')
uni_towns[["State","University"]] = uni_towns.Cleaned.str.split("(",n=1,expand=True) 
uni_towns["University"] = uni_towns["University"].str.rstrip(')')
cleaned_uni_towns = uni_towns[["State","University"]]
```

After this above step, I want to assign State to records whose above record has None assigned to it.
For Ex: Auburn (Auburn University)  current State is Auburn, but I want this to be updated to Alabama and similarly for records below Alabama till code encounters next State i.e. Alaska

This is the current output
[image: Current Output]

This is the expected output

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep put `NaN` in State when University is not `None` (i.e. that's a row with a university), then fill the `NaN` in State with the most recent non-`NaN` value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cleaned': ['Alabama', 'Auburn (Auburn University)', 'Alaska']})
df[['State', 'University']] = df.Cleaned.str.split('(', n = 1, expand = True)
df.University = df.University.str.rstrip(')')

df.State = np.where(df.University.map(lambda u: u is None), df.State, np.nan)
df.State = df.State.fillna(method = 'ffill')
```